# Exporting a torchscript model

Tags: pytorch, python-3.6, onnx, torchscript

I'm trying to convert a torchscript model to ONNX format. I'm using Pytorch 1.8.0. However I'm getting the errors when I try to run the following code.

```
device = torch.device('cpu')

trained_model.eval()
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    trained_model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model.pt'))
else:
    trained_model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model.pt'),map_location=device)


dummy_input = Variable(torch.randn(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

trained_model.eval()
torch.onnx.export(trained_model, dummy_input, "model.onnx",input_names = ['input'], output_names = ['output'])
```

The error is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py:589: UserWarning: 'torch.load' received a zip file that looks like a TorchScript archive dispatching to 'torch.jit.load' (call 'torch.jit.load' directly to silence this warning)
  " silence this warning)", UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 131, in <module>
    trained_model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model.pt',map_location=device))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 591, in load
    return torch.jit.load(opened_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/jit/_serialization.py", line 164, in load
    cu, f.read(), map_location, _extra_files
RuntimeError: Could not run 'aten::empty_strided' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend.This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build). If you are a Facebook employee using PyTorch on mobile, please visit https://fburl.com/ptmfixes for possible resolutions. 'aten::empty_strided' is only available for these backends: [CPU, BackendSelect, Named, AutogradOther, AutogradCPU, AutogradCUDA, AutogradXLA, AutogradNestedTensor, UNKNOWN_TENSOR_TYPE_ID, AutogradPrivateUse1, AutogradPrivateUse2, AutogradPrivateUse3, Tracer, Autocast, Batched, VmapMode].
```

When I tried to replace torch.load with torch.jit.load, I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "script.py", line 131, in <module>
    trained_model.load_state_dict(torch.jit.load('model.pt',map_location=device))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1196, in load_state_dict
    state_dict = state_dict.copy()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/jit/_script.py", line 561, in __getattr__
    return super(RecursiveScriptModule, self).__getattr__(attr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/jit/_script.py", line 291, in __getattr__
    return super(ScriptModule, self).__getattr__(attr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 948, in __getattr__
    type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'RecursiveScriptModule' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Basically how can I load the saved weights in the model to export them to onnx format? The Pytorch documentation covers normal pytorch models, but when I try to eecute the same steps for torxhscript models, its failing.

Comment: what type of model are you trying to import? what layers does it contain?
Sometimes certain layers are not yet supported by pytorch-onnx conversion.

Comment: Also, make sure your your model and weights are on the same device by adding `trained_model.to(device)` after defining the device.

Comment: I'm using standard layers such as Conv3D, BatchNorm3D, Conv2D, ReLU and MaxPool. Various combinations of this.

Comment: The layers are pretty standard so they should be the problem. Could you upload a minimal runnable version of your code?
Also - state the onnx version in the question as well as the pytorch version - this has some effect on which onnx opsets are available.

Comment: try adding opset_version `torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, 'model.onnx', opset_version=11)`